# Karate - Validate json responses stored in different files

Tags: karate

I need to validate 2 json responses which are stored in two different files. I am reading them and comparing. But i get an error `reason: all key-values did not match` and there're few elements not being matched. This problem occurs only when i store the json in a file and read in my feature file.

**Json File 1:** Test.json

```html
{
   "webServiceDetail":{
      "feature":{
         "featureCd":"ABCD",
         "imaginaryInd":"100.0",
         "extraInd1":"someRandomValue1"
      },
      "includefeatureList":[
         {
            "featureCd":"PQRS",
            "featureName":"Checking SecondAddOn Service",
            "extraInd1":"someRandomValue1",
            "extraInd2":"someRandomValue1"
         },
         {
            "featureCd":"XYZ",
            "featureName":"Checking AddOn Service",
            "imaginaryInd":"50.0"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**Json File 2:** Test1.json

```html
{
   "webServiceSummary":{
      "service":{
         "serviceCd":"ABCD"
      },
      "includeServicesList":[
         {
            "serviceCd":"XYZ",
            "serviceDescription": "Checking AddOn Service"
         },
         {
            "serviceCd":"PQRS",
            "serviceDescription":"Checking SecondAddOn Service"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Now, I am using below code to match two json files.

```
* def Test = read('classpath:PP1/data/Test.json')
* def Test1 = read('classpath:PP1/data/Test1.json')

* def feature = Test.webServiceDetail.feature
* set expected.webServiceSummary.service
| path               | value                |
| serviceCd          | feature.featureCd    |

* def mapper = function(x){ return { serviceCd: x.featureCd, serviceDescription: x.featureName} }
* def expectedList = karate.map(Test.webServiceDetail.includefeatureList, mapper)
* set expected.webServiceSummary.includeServicesList = expectedList
* print expected
* print Test1
* match Test1 == expected
```

Below is the error response.

```html
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: Test.feature:35 - path: $, actual: {webServiceSummary={service={serviceCd=ABCD}, includeServicesList=[{"serviceCd":"XYZ","serviceDescription":"Checking AddOn Service"},{"serviceCd":"PQRS","serviceDescription":"Checking SecondAddOn Service"}]}}, expected: {webServiceSummary={service={serviceCd=ABCD}, includeServicesList=[[object Object], [object Object]]}}, reason: all key-values did not match
```

Comment: If i store these 2 jsons in same feature file, everything works fine. Problem occurs only when i am reading from different files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but the order of `includeServicesList` is not matching. Make this one change:

```
* set expected.webServiceSummary.includeServicesList = '#(^^expectedList)'
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, this works. But in some cases, even though order is matching i get this [object Object] error when tried to match and '#(^^expectedList)' didn't worked (i.e., in some complex elements) Could you please help me with the logic in using '#(^^expectedList)'? I was not able to find this in github also.

Comment: I meant to say, in some cases, i need to use contains keyword. Like, * match Test1 contains expected - here, i again see error saying, expected: '#(^^expectedList)', reason: actual value does not contain expected. I am bit lost here!

Comment: @sandeephegde read the docs. take your time. open a new question if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate#contains-short-cuts