# Karate - Match two complex shuffled json

Tags: karate

Below question is very similar to this: [Karate - Validate json responses stored in different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53897591/karate-validate-json-responses-stored-in-different-files) I went through suggested contains-shortcuts and could not figure out the answer.

I need to compare two json files but using contains keyword. Why only contains? Because in some cases i need to match only some of the selected fields in json files. Below are the samples and codes.

**Json File 1: Test.Json**

```
{
   "webServiceDetail":{
      "feature":{
         "featureCd":"ABCD",
         "imaginaryInd":"100.0",
         "extraInd1":"someRandomValue1"
      },
      "includefeatureList":[
         {
            "featureCd":"PQRS",
            "featureName":"Checking SecondAddOn Service",
            "extraInd1":"someRandomValue1",
            "extraInd2":"someRandomValue1"
         },
         {
            "featureCd":"XYZ",
            "featureName":"Checking AddOn Service",
            "imaginaryInd":"50.0"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**Json File 2: Test1.json**

```
{
   "webServiceSummary":{
      "service":{
         "serviceCd":"ABCD"
      },
      "includeServicesList":[
         {
            "serviceCd":"XYZ",
            "serviceDescription": "Checking AddOn Service"
         },
         {
            "serviceDescription":"Checking SecondAddOn Service",
            "serviceCd":"PQRS",
            "randon":"FGDD"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**My Code:**

```
* def Test = read('classpath:PP1/data/test.json')
* def Test1 = read('classpath:PP1/data/Test1.json')
* def feature = Test.webServiceDetail.feature
* set expected.webServiceSummary.service
| path               | value                |
| serviceCd          | feature.featureCd    |

* def mapper = function(x){ return { serviceCd: x.featureCd, serviceDescription: x.featureName} }
* def expectedList = karate.map(Test.webServiceDetail.includefeatureList, mapper)
* set expected.webServiceSummary.includeServicesList = '#(^*expectedList)'
* match Test1.webServiceSummary.includeServicesList == expected.webServiceSummary.includeServicesList
```

Now, above code, perfectly works and i get success response as well. But my concern is I am matching with `contains any` here. I should verify with `contains` keyword. Because i need to ensure all the parameters in `expected.webServiceSummary.includeServicesList` are present in `Test1.webServiceSummary.includeServicesList`; not any or some of them. I tried using `#(^expectedList)` -- for contains; but didn't worked out. I know that these series of questions look silly, but i can't figure out the behavior!

Comment: sorry I'm going to request you to simplify your question. I also feel you are not reading the docs and just taking the easy way out and asking questions. also did you try `'#(^^blah)'` and read to docs to understand what it means.

Comment: Hi Peter, I read the documents and yes, tried with '#(^^expectedList)' as well but 
 doesn't get success. As i said, above code works for me, but according to the meaning it matches 'any' parameters not all of them.

Comment: And, I shortened as much as possible; i need to have minimum of these parameters to replicate the issue. You can ignore everything except Json file 1 and Json File 2. And sorry for asking lame questions; i worked on this for a day, couldn't get the response.

Comment: I can't understand your question. sorry.

Comment: I need to check whether all elements of `expected.webServiceSummary.includeServicesList` are present in `Test1.webServiceSummary.includeServicesList` but the code i am using is `'#(^*expectedList)'` which checks if ANY elements of response is present in source. But, I need to check ALL the elements of response, i.e., `expected.webServiceSummary.includeServicesList` are present is source. How can I achieve this?

Comment: that's what I said, the answer is `'#(^^expectedList)'`

Comment: I tried with this too; pls see the error. `path: $.webServiceSummary.includeServicesList[*], actual: [{"serviceCd":"XYZ","serviceDescription":"Checking AddOn Service"},{"serviceDescription":"Checking SecondAddOn Service","serviceCd":"PQRS","randon":"FGDD"}], expected: '#(^^expectedList)', reason: actual value does not contain expected`

Comment: try harder, start with simple data. most likely you have a typo or some silly mistake. hope someone else has the patience to help you. all the best

Comment: Thanks for your time Peter :)

Comment: Hello Sandeep, Did you found out answer for this? I have similar scenario too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will always check that a value `contains only` all the array elements in `expectedList`.

```
'#(^^expectedList)'
```

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#contains-short-cuts