# Karate - Matching Part Json with Parent

Tags: karate

Below is the json samples used for matching; match contains is not working.

```
* def Parent = [{ a: 1, b: 'x' }, { a: 2, b: 'y' }]
* def Part = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 'y' }]
* match Parent contains '#(^Part)'

# Below throws exception too.
* match Parent contains Part
```

Its throwing below error,

```
actual: [{"a":1,"b":"x"},{"a":2,"b":"y"}], expected: '#(^Part)', reason: actual value does not contain expected
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think is the best solution. Take your time to understand it ;)

```
* def data = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 'y' }]
* def response = [{ a: 1, b: 'x' }, { a: 2, b: 'y' }]
* def expected = karate.map(data, function(x, i){ return '#(^data[' + i + '])' })
* match response contains only expected
```

Since I expect this example to be useful as a reference to others and more, here is an alternative solution, which also showcases the new [dynamic scenario outlines](https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline) in 0.9.0. Note how `karate.map()` is one way to do loops, and there are other ways if you look at the docs and examples.

```
Background:
  * def data = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 'y' }]
  * def parts = karate.map(data, function(x){ return { part: x } })
  * def response = [{ a: 1, b: 'x' }, { a: 2, b: 'y' }]

  Scenario Outline:
    * def part = <part>
    * match response contains '#(^part)'

    Examples:
      | parts |
```

Comment: But, how can i match/validate when my second json has only few selected elements of each child? Like this `[{ a: 1 }, { b: 'y' }]`

Comment: i have NEVER seen a need for this, are you trying to test or just experiment. you can do this if you define part1 and part2. let that be homework for you. if you can’t figure out a solution, do it in 2 steps. all the best

Comment: Going through each child nodes and comparing might not be feasible considering length of some json files. Can we use some kinda if-else loop here? Like, we take `{a: 1}` first, check if its present in Parent using contains; then move on to `{b: x}` until all the nodes in part are completed.

Comment: Its not homework. Consider a scenario where, there are two json responses. I need to compare downstream response with API response. But, each downstream response contains only few elements of each child node, very similar to the one i have mentioned the question scenario. Since there'll be n number of dynamic child nodes, I cannot divide and check everytime right? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: there are multiple. search stack overflow. you can even use java. personally i think you are seriously over engineering your tests

Comment: I didn't found any. However, below question somewhat replicates my issue too! But, didn't found proper answer there as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902899/karate-match-two-complex-shuffled-json

Comment: Yes I do need this one! I have already converted my downstream json for comparing. Should i convert original response as well? That's like going round and round; checking on a solid way to compare the modified downstream response directly with API response. Please check case, on this whenever you get time. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Okay, Went through everything already. No way to replicate this case, unless modifying API response itself.
If we can't directly compare with contains keyword, which is easiest method, pls let me know. I'll go ahead to modify API response and compare. I am just searching for a solid way to match.

Comment: We are going sideways here! I never said, I hate to modify the API response. I already modified downstream response to match with my service response only to see match contains doesn't work if there's even a single extra key in the service response. Now, again i need to modify Service response as well if i need to use match contains!!!

Comment: extra key in response is standard. you seem to have invented a fantasy case where each array element is a different contains match. but sounds like you want to waste time finding how to do un-necessary stuff

Comment: Fine then! how are we suppose to match `[{ a: 1 }, { a: '2' }]` I have the same keys here. Even in this case i cannot use contains!

Comment: multiple ways. best is use a json path, extract the keys you want and then use match. or “match each” may work.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot Peter. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Nitheeshhunsur edited my answer. if it is not clear, please read the docs ;)